# Python: Error in online console python

Tags: python, console-application

I am using a online console of python: http://shell.appspot.com/ 
I am trying to write this code:

```
class tree:
 def __init__(self, charge, left=None, right=None):
  self.charge = charge
  self.left = left
  self.right = right
```

When I wrote the first line `class tree:` I push enter and I get this error from the console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/apps/shell/1.335852500710379686/shell.py", line 221, in get 
compiled = compile(statement, '<string>', 'single')
File "<string>", line 2
 ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Does anyone could tell me how to write this piece of code?
Thanks.

Comment: Downvoted as question does not show any research effort (the instruction is directly beneath it!)  Also, Stack Overflow is completely the wrong place to ask about this sort of thing. At best, Super User would be the place to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use ENTER.
 As indicated at the bottom of the online shell page use:

> Shift-Enter for newline

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the entire class into the text box in that application.  It is different from the usual Python shell, I know. :)

Paste in your code; it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter all the contents of the class at once. To go to a new line use `Shift+Enter`. For example, this worked for me -

```
class tree:        # press Shift+Enter here
    print 'aas'    # press Enter when you are done
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy it from here and paste it back. You probably had a wrong space in there somewhere, but it works if copied from here.